# My Triggers Error

Tags: mysql, triggers

My trigger stil error, 
it is my sql code

Query SQL:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `user`@`localhost` 
TRIGGER `trg_group` 
BEFORE DELETE ON `ref_group` 
FOR EACH ROW IF old.id = 1 OR old.name ='super_admin' THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This record is sacred! You are not allowed to remove it!!'
```

MySQL

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

whats wrong?

Comment: You have no end if statement nor delimiter statement.

Comment: And you'll want a semi-colon after your MESSAGE_TEXT string.

Comment: i forget it, but still error

Comment: CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `trg_group` BEFORE DELETE ON `ref_group` FOR EACH ROW IF old.id = 1 OR old.name ='super_admin' THEN 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'This record is sacred! You are not allowed to remove it!!';
END IF;